# Cleanup duplicate mails after fetchmail messed up the fetchids list

Tags: email, imap, duplicate, deduplication, fetchmail

I use fetchmail since years, to get my mails from a free private email provider, always with the "keep" option. Now, due to an update in mailu, the fetchids file got messed up and I have hundreds of duplicate mails in my mailbox.

I tried the thunderbird plugin [Remove Duplicate Messages](https://github.com/eyalroz/removedupes/) but it doesn't detect them as duplicates because they have newer Received: lines in the headers. On the other hand, I'm afraid of blindly removing all mails with such a `Received:` line and a date from yesterday, they are not necessarily duplicates.

What other options do I have to find these duplicates? The duplicates search should by kind of fuzzy, but only in the header. And they might even be located in different folders. I have access my server through thunderbird/imap.

Answer (score 0):

The [IMAPdedup](https://github.com/quentinsf/IMAPdedup) tool can remove duplicates by their `Message-ID` header, which is almost always unique (or optionally by a hash of "standard" headers, and/or the message body).